# Initializing a UIViewController correctly and passing in properties

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, ios8

I have a `UIViewController` called `TestViewController.h/.m`:

Header file has:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL isTested;
```

Implementation file has:

```
@implementation TestViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    if (_isTested)
    {
        [self postNotification];
        [self listenToNotifications];
    }
}
```

I have a view that has this:

```
- (void) replyTapPressed
{
    TestViewController *test = [[TestViewController alloc] init];

    test.isTested = NO;

    [_parent.navigationController pushViewController:test animated:YES];
}
```

Through the app's life cycle, the `TestViewController's` property starts off as `YES;` but when the view about gets called, it should set the property to `NO`; - which it does.

But _parent (which is the parent `UIViewController`) and test are both `NULL`.

Am I initializing and implementing it wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: `test.isTested = NO;`
 `[self.navigationController pushViewController:test animated:YES];`

Comment: Why do you assigning objects – `@NO`, `@YES` – to BOOL property?

Comment: Your question is not clear. You said that you set `isTested` to NO properly, but then you say that `test` is null -- if `test` is null you can't set any of its properties.  Also, what is _parent? How is that property (or ivar) set?

Comment: The debugger says test (TestViewController *) null (but not nil) and why does this happen? thx

Answer (score 0):

You may try in below ways -

**TestViewController.m**

```
- (id)initWithTested:(BOOL)value
{

    if (self = [super init])
    {
        self.isTested = value;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) replyTapPressed
{
    TestViewController *test = [[TestViewController alloc] initWithTested:NO];

    [_parent.navigationController pushViewController:test animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The view will "load" during initialization of your controller. To achieve what you want, implement viewWillAppear and move

```
if (_isTested) {
    [self postNotification];
    [self listenToNotifications]; 
}
```

there. (You could also put this in  `viewDidAppear`, depending on what you are doing.)